# How to dismiss the <meta> tag?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to show in an alert a french sentence containing accentuated letters such as "é" and "à". So I use the utf-8 charset in the meta tag of my php file so that the letters "é" and "à" are displayed normally in a javascript alert. The problem is that when getting the ajax responseText then I get among the responses the code of the meta tag. So how to get only the echo result of the php file ?

Here is the php file used by the ajax :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php   
define("ROOT_PATH", "../../");
include ROOT_PATH . 'config.ajax.php';
include ROOT_PATH . 'config.inc.php';
require_once RP_MODELS.'produit.class.php';

$prod_code = $_GET['prod_code'];

$db =& new DbConn() ;   
$produit =& new produit($db->getInstance()) ;
$tab = $produit->lire($prod_code) ;

if ( $tab['cnt'] > 0)
    $rep = "Le code produit " . $prod_code . " existe déjà !" ;
else 
    $rep = "0" ;

echo $rep;

?>
```

So I want only the $rep variable to be returned by the ajax responseText. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php   
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
define("ROOT_PATH", "../../");
include ROOT_PATH . 'config.ajax.php';
include ROOT_PATH . 'config.inc.php';
require_once RP_MODELS.'produit.class.php';

$prod_code = $_GET['prod_code'];

$db =& new DbConn() ;   
$produit =& new produit($db->getInstance()) ;
$tab = $produit->lire($prod_code) ;

if ( $tab['cnt'] > 0)
    $rep = "Le code produit " . $prod_code . " existe déjà !" ;
else 
    $rep = "0" ;

echo $rep;    

?>
```

Read:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the meta tag on this script. You only need it on pages that the browser is going to have to render.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the html code including meta tag from this file and use

```
echo utf8_encode($rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the request is an Ajax request, try something like this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // This is an ajax request
    echo $rep;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a variable to the url by which you can recognize the AJAX request, or you can set a special [X-Requested-With](http://www.developertutorials.com/learn-ajax/custom-http-headers-2643.php) header (which I think it automatically set by JQuery). In PHP you can check if this header is set.

Also, don't forget to set the Content-Type header, in which you should also specify UTF-8.